# How long until quantum computers are able to decrypt RSA using Shor's algorithm?

Tags: cryptography, decryption, quantum-computing

Based on this question:

[How many qubits are needed to factor 2048-bit RSA keys on a quantum computer?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/87345/how-many-qubits-are-needed-to-factor-2048-bit-rsa-keys-on-a-quantum-computer)

It's going to take 20-30 years for quantum computers to reach that state but some people are giving much shorter estimates. So what is the most probable estimate?

Obviously, I'm just asking about an estimate. I want to know is it possible that they start breaking RSA like next year?! or maybe 5-6 years, or...?

Do we even need to worry about this or has a good solution already been proposed?

Comment: I don't think anyone can give even a reasonably good estimate to this question.  There's simply too many unknowns.  It's more than simply increasing the amount of qubits.  One of the current problems is simply maintaining a quantum state for a long period of time.  You can't provide estimates on breakthroughs.  This is still within the realm of edge science, not just silicon process shrinks/Moore's law.

Comment: unless something wildly unexpected by experts happens, you have at least 10 years before the first small RSA keys are broken.

Comment: As far as solutions, a new science has been created just for that purpose, post-quantum cryptography.